# Linux soft RAID5 does not come up after multiple power failures on some discs, what to do?

Tags: linux, software-raid, data-recovery, electrical-power

I have a backup of all important data. At the end a restore is needed. But I want to first try something before I would go this way and it is a good situation to learn something about all the stuff I used here.

I have a mpt sas controller with 8 SATA Channel connected to two internal 2,5" disc bays configured.
Two of them were used for SSD drives, which are only used for caching lvm volumes.

6 1 TB discs are used for a dataparts on partition 3 configured as a RAID5 soft array.

Two of them have been used for bootparts on partition 1 and rootparts for partition 2. Both bootparts are a simple RAID1 with ext3 fs.
Both bootparts are a RAID1 which is encrypted with luks and and has a lvm vg xenrootdg with several lvs.
All 6 dataparts are used as a RAID5 as described. The raid volume is luks encrypted and on these a lvm with a vg xendatadg. Only on the RAID5 volume has problems to bring them up.

The main issue was multiple power failures on the 4 discs enclosure which holds 4 of the six 1TB discs. A new disc has to been added because of a removed disc, maybe near to the end the new disc has to been resynced. This is not exactly known.

I could start the volume after the first failure and could start a resync. But the problem occurs again and so these RAID volume failed again.

At the time of the second failure the system could not read sectors of a special disc and the RAID5 has become degraded because of a logged permanent read error of some sector of one of the failed discs.

In the meantime, the discs re-registred by the kernel with new name (eg. has renamed from sde to sdk and so on).

After restart of the system I checked which disc it was logged as failed and found them by comparing the serial number. A dd of the disc to /dev/zero has not shown any problems so I tried to resync again but the same issue occurs.

Now I realised that it could be a problem with the disc bay power so I removed all discs and at least connected them on existing SATA ports on the mainboard. I added more discs to the sas controller so I could make a backup on the partitions now by using dd.

I was able to copy all related partitions to two new discs so reading is not a problem.

Also only max. of 3 volumes inside the lvm vg was been in use. So most lvs should be still in clean state because has not modified after I removed the first disc #2 (sdl3).

I checked smartctl so there is no permanent problem on a disc itself registered (no unrecoverable errors and no relocated sectors shown).

But I'm not able to start the RAID5 volume although it should have enough discs.

I have
5 disc (#0,1,3,4,5) and the still existing removed disc #2.
Also the new replacing disc #2 is there but shown as spare.
It should be possible to bring the volume up with #0,1,3,4,5 which are 5 of 6 volumes available.
But whatever I try at least #3 makes me most of all problems because is never accepted as a part of the volume.

Because of sdX could change here the examine in the order of device role shown.
Here a short list for the moment:

#0 sdc3
#1 sdk3
#3 sda3
#4 sdg3
#5 sdf3

removed #2 sdl3
new #2 marked a #S sdb3

```
root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 1909221936 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260912 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1142cc76:b224395c:8fb15126:fd1801fe

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan 16 00:02:32 2024
       Checksum : bae896cd - correct
         Events : 248741

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AARA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

   root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sdk3
/dev/sdk3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 1909221936 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260912 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 701ed2ed:13a03708:da9cc185:9c9ce3e2

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan 16 10:26:32 2024
       Checksum : 223defb1 - correct
         Events : 248741

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A...A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

   root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sdl3
/dev/sdl3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 1909221936 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260912 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1b34e8d5:f3df3e52:307a06a0:38c265e4

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Mon Jan 15 13:36:40 2024
       Checksum : 7023234b - correct
         Events : 248741

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

   root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x83
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 1909221936 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260912 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fa9d44c6:bb18bc8c:04ed5943:13a6ddfb

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan 16 00:02:32 2024
       Checksum : 55c99a69 - correct
         Events : 243265

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA.A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

   root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sdg3
/dev/sdg3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8b
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 1909221936 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260904 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 63a171d2:dad103ed:ff18efc4:d31bc05d

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan 16 10:22:01 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : a5b990c1 - correct
         Events : 244946

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : .AA.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

   root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sdf3
/dev/sdf3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 1909221936 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260912 sectors, after=1200 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : d6e11e48:e1258598:f9d5251c:795c8308

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan 16 10:26:32 2024
       Checksum : c8dc31e3 - correct
         Events : 248741

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : .A...A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

Here the replacing disc
root@newxen:~# mdadm -E /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x9
     Array UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
           Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov  8 22:22:15 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 7720024847 (3681.19 GiB 3952.65 GB)
     Array Size : 4773051840 (4551.94 GiB 4887.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1909220736 (910.39 GiB 977.52 GB)
    Data Offset : 260992 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260912 sectors, after=5810804111 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1be91027:ca00bcc9:7e21dd61:76cdf787

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan 16 10:26:32 2024
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : f892a18d - correct
         Events : 248741

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .A...A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

Situation now:

```
root@newxen:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md128 : inactive sda3[3](S) sdb3[6](S) sdf3[5](S) sdc3[0](S) sdg3[2](S) sdk3[1](S)
      8633067263 blocks super 1.2
...

root@newxen:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md128
/dev/md128:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 6

              Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
              UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
            Events : 248741

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8      163        -        /dev/sdk3
       -       8       99        -        /dev/sdg3
       -       8       83        -        /dev/sdf3
       -       8       35        -        /dev/sdc3
       -       8       19        -        /dev/sdb3
       -       8        3        -        /dev/sda3
```

If I check the latest date and Array State so I mean at first
Jan 15 13:36:40 sdl3 has to been set failed and removed (which i made manually) with AAAAAA but should be clean
Jan 16 00:02:32 sda3 with AAAA.A looks like clean
Jan 16 00:02:32 sdc3 with AARA.A looks like clean
Jan 16 10:22:01 sdg3 with .AA.AA looks like not clean
Jan 16 10:26:32 sdk3 with .A...A looks like not clean
Jan 16 10:26:32 sdf3 with .A...A looks like clean
Jan 16 10:26:32 sdb3 with .A..A looks like not clean

It should be possible to assemble the raid volume with the existing parts sda3 sdc3 sdg3 sdk3 sdf3 maybe because of it was in the array sdb3.

I tried different methods but none of them brings me back to an resyncing volume.

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose
...
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdl3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdf3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 5.
mdadm: /dev/sdg3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sdk3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdc3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdb3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot -1.
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdk3 as it reports /dev/sdl3 as failed
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdf3 as it reports /dev/sdl3 as failed
mdadm: device 12 in /dev/md128 has wrong state in superblock, but /dev/sdb3 seems ok
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 1 of /dev/md128
mdadm: added /dev/sdl3 to /dev/md128 as 2
mdadm: added /dev/sda3 to /dev/md128 as 3 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdg3 to /dev/md128 as 4 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 5 of /dev/md128
mdadm: added /dev/sdb3 to /dev/md128 as -1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc3 to /dev/md128 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md128 assembled from 2 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.
...
root@newxen:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md128 : inactive sdf3[5](S) sdb3[6](S) sdc3[0](S) sdk3[1](S) sdg3[2](S) sdl3[4](S)
      8633067263 blocks super 1.2
...
root@newxen:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md128
/dev/md128:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 6
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 6

              Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
              UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
            Events : 248741

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8      179        -        /dev/sdl3
       -       8      163        -        /dev/sdk3
       -       8       99        -        /dev/sdg3
       -       8       83        -        /dev/sdf3
       -       8       35        -        /dev/sdc3
       -       8       19        -        /dev/sdb3
```

So it looks like the old removed sdl3 and replacemend sdb3 makes some trouble.
So stopped md128 again and tried to bring it up manually without them:

```
root@newxen:~# mdadm --assemble /dev/md128 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdk3 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdg3 /dev/sdf3 --verbose
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md128
mdadm: /dev/sdc3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdk3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sda3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/sdg3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 4.
mdadm: /dev/sdf3 is identified as a member of /dev/md128, slot 5.
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdk3 as it reports /dev/sdc3 as failed
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdg3 as it reports /dev/sdc3 as failed
mdadm: ignoring /dev/sdf3 as it reports /dev/sdc3 as failed
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 1 of /dev/md128
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 2 of /dev/md128
mdadm: added /dev/sda3 to /dev/md128 as 3 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 4 of /dev/md128
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 5 of /dev/md128
mdadm: added /dev/sdc3 to /dev/md128 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md128 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.

root@newxen:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md128 : inactive sdk3[1](S) sdf3[5](S) sdg3[2](S) sdc3[0](S)
      3818443872 blocks super 1.2
...

root@newxen:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md128
/dev/md128:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 4

              Name : newxen:128  (local to host newxen)
              UUID : 8d0acbbb:73bcfac9:a26557de:c29d5434
            Events : 248741

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8      163        -        /dev/sdk3
       -       8       99        -        /dev/sdg3
       -       8       83        -        /dev/sdf3
       -       8       35        -        /dev/sdc3
```

So I wonder me sda3 is not shown in the details.

I tried also to use sdl3 instead of sdb3 and tried to re-add the missing parts but nothing really helped.
So I guess I should zero the superblocks and recreate the raid with --assume-clean option.
In my opinon it shoud bo in the correct order. At best maybe it should be without sdb3 and sdl3 because
I'm not sure that sdb3 has ever arrived the sync state before the first problem occured. Is there a way to check it?

So if no other option exists I would do (is this order correct?)

```
mdadm --create --verbose --force --assume-clean /dev/md128 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdk3 missing /dev/sda3 /dev/sdg3 /dev/sdf3
```

Another solution could be if I assume the disk sdb3 has to been almost synced.

```
mdadm --create --verbose --force --assume-clean /dev/md128 --level=5 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdk3 /dev/sdb3 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdg3 /dev/sdf3
```

How can I check it?:

```
echo check >> /sys/block/md128/md/sync_action and then check dmesg carefully?
```

Another thing what I would to know is in which sectors I must be prepared for problems after the reconstruction has to been finished? Any suggestions how I can identify them?

Added more details:
It's hard to find detailed information. So it would be nice if someone can confirm or correct my ideas.

In the meantime the decrypt tests has to been finished. No permutation of the device order has to been worked well.

So it was possible by bring the RAID array up and running by the way the data itself looks like still mixed an is still unusable. Because of that, I cannot decrypt the luks data on them for the moment.

Comment: Recover from backup. Find a service who recovers data from RAID and pay them. Lastly, STFW, including **Linux RAID wiki** (a first-party documentation!) and ServerFault (here), **there are instructions what to do**.

Comment: Not really helpfull because I did allready search the web and tried some possible solutions. Payment is no option for this private usage so my time is the only payment which I can spent. But my winning is learning more about the layout of the soft raid.
At best I can learn how to recover the volume without using md stuff :-)

Comment: SMART is not a valid source to know if a disk is in good shape, it may give you only a hint. If you ask me, I would guess a hardware failure of one of your disks. Several power on/offs in short time can destroy electrical hardware.

Comment: Yes, but after I cleared the problem comes from a bad power source for 4 disks and have fixed I could read all disks by copy the partition data to a new disks so this is not further a problem here and will not answer my question.

Comment: I come to an answer by my self athough it does not helped me to save my data, but it is helpful enough so anyone which will become to similar situation could use it.

Comment: RAID5. SATA. Old hardware at end of life. Checking a lot of "worst practice" boxes here

Comment: This should have a TLDR at the to